# PHP 5.4.31 + Zend Guard configuration issue

Tags: php, zend-guard, phpfarm

I am configuring a Ubuntu 14.04 web server at Amazon Web Services. I have the latest PHP5.5 installed as base, but I am using [PHP Farm](https://github.com/cweiske/phpfarm) so that I can use PHP5.4.31 for a specific project that requires Zend Guard, which is only compatible with PHP up to 5.4.x. I added these lines to my custom php.ini

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/php/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so
zend_extension=/usr/local/php/ZendGuardLoader.so
```

So, everything works fine, but when I compile the PHP custom build I get this in the end:

```
Cannot load the ionCube PHP Loader - it was built with configuration API220100525,NTS, whereas running engine is API220100525,NTS,debug
Cannot load Zend Guard Loader - it was built with configuration API220100525,NTS, whereas running engine is API220100525,NTS,debug
```

Now from what can be seen, the builds are the same, the only differnce is:

```
API220100525,NTS vs. API220100525,NTS,debug
```

What I understand from this is that the PHP Zend Engine is running in Debug mode, but I can't seem to find how to disable debug mode so that the extensions can be activated.

Any ideas?

Comment: probably can't disable debug. a debug compile adds a whole whack of "scaffolding" code. you'd have to find a non-debug compile.

Comment: I downloaded it automatically through PHPFarm, is there a configure  option to select which type?

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled upon the same error.
Thanks to Marc B's hint I had a look into PHPFarm's compile.sh

There's a standard-option defined:

```
--enable-debug
```

just remove this line, delete your compiled php stuff in

```
/path/to/phpfarm/src/php-5.x
```

and recompile with

```
./compile.sh 5.x
```

Afterwards you should have a non-debug version which will work with ZendGuardLoader

Comment: I ended up compiling 5.4.30, but I think I had removed the --with-debug flag but I hadn't deleted the previous installation so it kind of didn't refresh with the new settings.